# How to make Hamburger Menu Lines in bootstrap another color?

Tags: css, bootstrap-5, hamburger-menu

I have a hamburger menu appear with medium screen sizes and lower and I want to change the color of the lines of the hamburger icon

I've tried changing it with the style attributes and I've tried using !important in my css file but still nothing works

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap uses `svg` images as icons, so we can't change the `color`, as it is an image.

Use the below CSS code:-

```
.navbar-toggler-icon {
            background-image: url(
"data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 32 32' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath stroke='rgba(0, 128, 0, 0.8)' stroke-width='2' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' d='M4 8h24M4 16h24M4 24h24'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
        }
```

**In the above code, at this statement
`stroke='rgba(your desired color code)'` , you can use your own color codes.NOTE: Try to keep the whole url in a single line like the above.**

**Make sure to link your external `CSS` file after your `bootstrap` link in the `<head>` section.**

I hope you get it!

Comment: I've tried it but it doesn't work

Comment: Check now , i have edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to apply CSS specificity.

nav>button>.navbar-toggler-icon {
background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,') !important;
}

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-light">
  <button class="navbar-toggler collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```